# finding the correct language, library or piece of software to 3D model

Tags: 3d

I need to model some designs I have made into an stl format so they can be 3d printed.

The designs are mathematically modelled and have variable parameters (for example angles and lengths). These variables influence multiple aspects of the design and I need to find a piece of software or language/and or libraries to automatically change the values from a custom user interface that I can design.

As an example, imagine a simple fan, with simple blades that are positioned at “x” degree intervals, with “y” total thickness, “z” blade thickness, and so on. I need to be able to input the variables and then the program automatically executes the code (obviously designed pre-made for the general shape given the variables) and generates the structure. Anyone have any ideas? I’m aware I could manually model them but there are a lot of very similar components that only differ by a few variables

Comment: STL is available as a text file, so if you have programming capabilities you can modify the appropriate strings with the correct limits.